# Element focus with Angular Material 2 and SideNav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm Angular Material 2 and having trouble setting focus on a specific element with the SideNav.  I've tried a couple of approaches that don't seem to work.  I have a side nav component as such:

```
<md-sidenav #globalsidenav (open)="onNavWindowOpened($event)">
```

I've created a element like such:

```
<a #manageAccount>Manage Account></a>
```

Inside my component I use a reference to the element via ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('manageAccount') manageAccount;
```

Then on the open event handler try and and set focus on the element:

```
onNavWindowOpened(event) {
  console.log('open event received...');

  this.manageAccount.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

I've also tried it 'manually' by looking up the element and changing the focus but to no avail.  Is there any other approach that should work in a scenario like this?

Comment: maybe you need to prevent the event from bubbling up as mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#Notes

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the attribute directive below:

```
cdkFocusRegionstart
```

In your example:

```
<a #manageAccount cdkFocusRegionstart>Manage Account></a>
```

Then the anchor should be focused as soon as the sidenav opens.

See discussion on github here:
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3265